# Accessing the layers of an eps with photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've had a couple of web clients send me logos from their printer in EPS format. They claim all the "layers" are accessible but when I open in Photoshop, I can only see one layer, or rather the image I open is complete, but only appears to HAVE one layer. Is it possible to access the layers via photoshop or do I need to use another tool? Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried opening the EPS in Illustrator?  Usually logos are vector images made using vector image editing software, not raster image editors such as Photoshop.

Comment: I agree with Billy.. if the EPS files are vector EPS files, Photoshop simply will never see any layers. Photoshop sees vector images as one layer, one file, one smart object. You can use a vector app -- Illustrator, Inkscape -- to possibly se the layers.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've tagged this explicitly with Photoshop, and you re-iterate that choice in your question - but as you've already heard in a couple of spot-on comments, in this case a frame challenge is the *only* **appropriate** response:

EPS is s self-ecapsulated graphics format [*defined*](https://web.archive.org/web/20170818010030/http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/postscript/pdfs/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf) in the Adobe [*Post-Script*](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript.html) language, which can include vector graphics and raster and is ***best*** handled by vector graphics software designed for such tasks.

Photoshop is by definition a raster graphics software package, which can handle some vector graphics (if inelegantly) and is therefore the ***wrong*** software choice for this task.

Open this in a vector design package such as [**Adobe Illustrator**](https://www.adobe.com/it/products/illustrator.html), [**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/), or [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/), and you should see a *wholly different* document structure.

Hopefully this (and the previous comments) is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, your answers are very helpful. I just discovered InkScape and am opening now. I ended up solving my initial problems but simply "cutting" all the individual elements out of logo, deleting the white background, and making my own layers. Luckily none of the layers was overlapping any other, which allowed this "hack". Thanks again for the suggestions, which will help me the next time around!